# React router how do I include header links in the browser router without the header itself updating on redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am fairly new to react but I have been told when making a website its good practice to have a layout component which holds the header, page content and footer however when using react router I want the header and footer to not update just the page content but if I add the links in the header outside the browserrouter tag I get a error saying they need to be inside but if i then include them inside the header updates along with the content..

In the header I have a navbar with links like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
    return(
        <nav className="header-links">
            <Link to="/" className="link">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/about" className="link">About</Link>
            <Link to="/contact" className="link">Contact Us</Link>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default HeaderNav;
```

Then in the layout file I include the header which has the links

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './header/header'
import Footer from './footer/footer'


const PageLayout = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <div className="layout-wrapper">
            <Header />
            <main className="site-content">{children}</main>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}

export default PageLayout;
```

Then I also have a router file with my routes:

```
import React from 'react'
import HomePage from './pages/home'
import AboutPage from './pages/about'
import ContactPage from './pages/contact'
import {
  Switch,
  Route,
  BrowserRouter
} from 'react-router-dom';

const Routes = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
      <Route exact path="/contact" component={ContactPage} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Routes;
```

The problem that I am having is if in the layout.js I only wrap the page content in the browserrouter tag then I get a error saying my links need to be inside this BUT if I then wrap the header, page content and footer in the browserrouter then they all update when a link is clicked so I am struggling with how do I include the links in the browserrouter without the header updating?

For instance:

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './header/header'
import Footer from './footer/footer'


const PageLayout = ({children}) => {
    return (
        <div className="layout-wrapper">
            <Routes>
            <Header />
            <main className="site-content">{children}</main>
            <Footer />
            <Routes />
        </div>
    );
}

export default PageLayout;
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be totally off base here, but I'm pretty sure you want something like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Header/>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
      <Route exact path="/contact" component={ContactPage} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Woudnt that still update the header though being that the header is inside the browserrouter tag?

Comment: What do you mean by 'update'? The header wouldn't change, I don't think.

Comment: Do you mean 're-render'?

Comment: Sorry yes re render